# C++ arithmetic operator overloading when using template--automatic converting

Tags: c++, templates

I encountered a problem when I'm implementing the vector-op-scalar operators for my short-vector class. And the code lists as follows:

```
template<class T>
class Vec3
{
    Vec3& operator*=( const T& rhs );
};
template<class T>
Vec3<T> operator*( const Vec3<T>& lhs, const T& rhs );
Vec3<float> a;
a*=3; // right 
a*3; // wrong
```

Well, I'm really surprised that for the operator*=, as I expected, the constant integer 3 can be automatically convert to float, but for the operator*, it couldn't, and resulting a compile error lists below:

> error C2782: 'Vec3 operator *(const Vec3 &,T)' : template parameter 'T' is ambiguous
>
> main.cpp(162) : see declaration of 'operator *'  could be 'int' or       'float'

I'm really confused about this and have no idea about why it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first (`*=`), `T` template parameter was already resolved at variable decleration, and so the function was already created with the signature `Vec3& operator*=( const float& rhs )`, which can now be called with an `int`.

In the second, the compiler is now trying to create the appropiate function based on the template parameter, and it is getting two different types - `float` for the `lhs` and `int` for `rhs` - both for the same template parameter, and so does not know how to create the function signature.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T>
Vec3<T> operator*( const Vec3<T>& lhs, const T& rhs );
```

if lhs is a Vec3 and rhs is an int, the compiler is just confused what version of your templated-function it should use (the int- or the float- version).
Try writing `a * 3.0f`.
You can also add the operator* directly to your class, this way the compiler invokes the method on the type `Vec3<float>` so the type on the right of your asterix is always converted to float.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer :). a * 3.0f works. Vec3<T> operator*(const Vec3<T> &lhs, T rhs) still have the same problem.

Comment: You might add the operator* directly to the class. This way, the compiler invokes the method on the type Vec3<float>, so there is no confusion.

Comment: Yes, but I also need another operator,which takes the scalar as the lhs. i.e.: template<class T> Vec3<T> operator*( const T& lhs, const Vec3<T>& rhs );

Comment: So maybe I can use template<class T, class U>
Vec3<T> operator*( const U& lhs, const Vec3<T>& rhs ) to handle my case...or, just write 3.0f * a

Answer (score 1):

When you call member operator, the signature is already known to the compiler

```
Vec3& operator*=( const float& rhs );
```

It needs to perform an implicit conversion between `int` and `float`. No problem with that.

When you call the template `operator*`, it needs to *deduce* the `T` and that can only succeed if it can de deduced to the same type for each usage of `T` in the signature. No type conversion is performed here. Compiler sees that it's `float` once and `int` the other time, so it errors out.

One workaround would be to declare the free operator with two different template parameteres and delegate the actual work to the member operator inside it.

```
template<typename T, typename U>
Vec3<T> operator* const Vec3<T>& lhs, const U& rhs )
{
    return lhs *= rhs;
}
```

Now the compiler can do the type conversion between parameters and error out if it's not possible.

Comment: I agree that free binary operators like `*` should be inplemented in terms of member operators like `*=`. We should also provide free overloads where the types are swapped. Also: doesn't your `operator*` need (a) an opening parenthesis and (b) to take `lhs` by value so that `operator*=` can actually be called, on a copy, which it can't on a `const` instance?